# NoSuchMethodError when using a customized netty codec with maven (compiler target to 1.8)

Tags: java, maven, netty

I am maintaining a httpServer library that's built on netty and it uses a customized `netty-codec-http`. The library is supposed to work for java version >= 8. It works fine on java 12, but not on java 8. Can someone please help getting it to work on java8.

I understand that the problem is most likely related to the changes to ByteBuffer interface on java9. However, I couldn't get it to work. What I have tried so far

1. Build the `netty-codec-http` and httpServer library on java8 (compiler source and target set to 1.8) and run on java8
2. Build the `netty-codec-http` and httpServer library on java12 (compiler source=12 and target=1.8) and run on java8
3. Setting the release version to 8

**Exception when using the library**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.clear()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.internalNioBuffer(PooledByteBuf.java:158)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf._internalNioBuffer(PooledByteBuf.java:188)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.internalNioBuffer(PooledByteBuf.java:201)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:253)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1133)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:350)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Maven settings

```
//version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec
Java version: 13.0.2, vendor: N/A, runtime: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/13.0.2+8_2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"


//command
cd /../netty
mvn clean install -pl codec-http -am
```

**netty-codec-http pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-parent</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.49.Final</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>4.1.49.Final.custom.1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>Netty/Codec/HTTP</name>

  <properties>
    <javaModuleName>io.netty.codec.http</javaModuleName>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-common</artifactId>
      <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-buffer</artifactId>
      <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
      <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-codec</artifactId>
      <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
      <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
      <artifactId>jzlib</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**httpServer library pom.xml**

```
<project //...>
//...
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.49.Final.custom.1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.49.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.30.Final</version>
            <classifier>linux-x86_64</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is result of compiling with java9+ and running with java8. The cause is that in java9 ByteBuffer overrides some methods, for example flip(), and returns ByteBuffer back, while java8 was returning Buffer. Recompile your code with jdk8 and problem should be solved.

Comment: I tried that before, but I'll give it another try now. But shouldn't maven.compiler.target=1.8 handle that already?

Comment: this is the change of API. The maven.compiler.target controls only the output format of the class files. However, according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm, maven.compiler.release should do that. You need maven compile plugin version 3.8.0 and newer, of course.